# Can I have my trackpad use one speed, while my actual mouse have a different speed?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I want my trackpad's mouse speed to be the second notch up in the settings, like this:

[image: trackpad speed]

I have an actual mouse whose speed I want to be all the way up in the settings, like this:

[image: mouse speed]

My USB dongle for the mouse is *always* plugged in. It's a lenovo laptop with the built-in mousepad software that comes with it.

Comment: [How To Set Different Speeds for Your Trackpad and External Mouse](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45366/how-to-set-different-speeds-for-your-trackpad-and-external-mouse/)

Comment: @JamesScholes It appears (unless I'm misreading something) that both of those programs will bug you about paying them unless you buy a key. Personally, I hate programs like that (I personally never put that stuff in mine) and was wondering if you knew of any programs that don't do that?

Comment: It's mentioned in the article that Autosensitivity doesn't nag you, but it is .NET-based so you take the rough with the smooth :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a separate driver software for your trackpad such as Synaptics. You can change the sensitivity of your trackpad through which you can gain the control of pointer speed. I hope that would solve your problem.

Comment: I have Synaptics and it doesn't have pointer speed control

Answer (score 4):

Just came across EitherMouse.  It's working well for me so far

•Instantly changes settings when any mouse is used: ◦swap buttons
◦mirror cursor
◦adjust speeds
◦and more...

•Leave multiple mice on a pc and automatically swap buttons on each mouse.

•Have a left-handed and a right-handed mouse always connected and ready to use.

•Match speeds across different mice, ie touchpad and mouse with different speeds.

•Accommodate left and right handed users easily on multi-user or public workstations.

•Helps prevent RSI/injury issues by allowing seemless switching between hands.

•Quickly change mouse settings from system tray if only one mouse is used

http://www.eithermouse.com/

Comment: Could you expand upon why and how this software solves the OPs issue? Please see [how to recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: @Burgi - this program absolutely solves the problem !

Comment: A shame you've been downvoted - this program is lightweight and free and does exactly what the original poster wanted.  I came with the same question.  Thanks...

Comment: This works well. Should be built into Windows!

Answer (score 1):

A potential avenue to solve your problem is that some mice, like several --but not necessarily all-- Logitech, for example my G500, have their own independent (eg. dpi settings in gaming mouses) or semi-independent (appears to be an offset or acceleration added to the basic windows speed in regular mouses) speed control in their custom driver.

In a way, such a mouse would solve your problem: the touchpad would use the windows setting, and the mouse with a custom driver would work with different settings.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still relevant I guess. In my case I wanted my touchpad to move faster than my external mouse. What worked for me is turning on the "momentum" option from the synaptics driver. This makes the pointer move on after you take your finger of the touchpad, as if it were a ball keeping rolling. 
Not the perfect solution, but it makes the slow setting (which is ideal for my external mouse) workable on the touchpad for me.

Wouldn't work for the opposite situation unfortunately (wanting faster setting for touchpad, as topic starter's situation)