# Is there a way to change the mouse settings on ONLY a USB connected mouse?

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

I have an old IBM Model M13 keyboard with a PS/2-to-USB adapter that has a pointing stick built into it that I like using a lot. However, I think it has some unusual DPI or something because whatever I plug it into, the mouse moves *very* slowly. On linux I can simply use xinput to toggle the acceleration settings for that specific device. But in Windows 10 (or possibly other versions, too?) I can't seem to find a way to change the settings for specifically the USB mouse and not the entire system. I don't want it to affect the touchpad or any other mouse that's connected to the computer.

Is there some way to change only the mouse settings for the mouse connected via USB? Is there some 3rd party tool that will allow me to access and alter these settings?

Comment: [Setting mouse sensitivity per device in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/225686/241386), [Is there a way to adjust mouse pointer speed for individual monitors?](https://superuser.com/q/826880/241386), [Mouse cursor on multiple screens with different PPI](https://superuser.com/q/1051269/241386), [Can I have my trackpad use one speed, while my actual mouse have a different speed?](https://superuser.com/q/587692/241386), [How to change mouse to left handed but keep touchpad right handed?](https://superuser.com/q/907216/241386)

Comment: Thanks @phuclv I guess I was searching superuser for the wrong terms. Though it looks like a lot of those links are no longer available. I was able to find a copy of the autohotkey variation through the web archive though.

Comment: Not exactly understand your issue. Do you mean you like to use pointing stick,  so you want to make some configuration on USB mouse? But as the slow issue occur when you plug USB mouse into PC, we could consider to update USB mouse driver. If you want to apply specify setting on USB, I recomend to change through registry. Before that we should use regshot to capture the registry key for USB mouse.

Comment: Hi @Joy, I want to be able to use the pointing stick on the IBM keyboard (via USB) as well as the touchpad on the laptop itself, depending on which screen I'm actually sitting in front of. But the mouse settings from the control panel control both. I'll take a look at regshot

Comment: I would appreciate if you could share your research and test results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to phuclv's comment, I was directed to Eithermouse. Although their domain's DNS isn't resolving, I was able to find a pretty recent archive from [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180807161635/https://www.eithermouse.com/). I downloaded it and it was pretty easy to setup. I can now set the mouse speed for the touchpad on the laptop, the IBM Model M13's pointing stick, as well as a 3rd bluetooth mouse individually. I wish that it allowed me to arbitrarily set mouse speeds as even on the highest speed allowed by the UI, the IBM pointing stick is still too slow. I've tried tweaking the scripts and even tried using Joy's suggestion of regshot but I couldn't find anything that made it move faster together with eithermouse.

I've also found a more recent application called [Plural Input](https://pluralinput.com/) which I've tried as well. It has more features including setting up multiple keyboards and limiting cursors to different displays. The interface is much nicer but it will install its own driver and it says that it eventually will require a fee. Unfortunately, it doesn't show any of my devices once I've added them to the driver, but I'll continue to keep it updated as it looks more promising. Maybe others will have better luck.

Comment: I came looking for a solution. Thank you. However I will add a late response to update this 3 year old question. Let me know if and when you might want to update your answer with the information I have.

Answer (score 0):

To update the accepted answer, eithermouse.com is functioning again. However Chrome and Firefox block the download as dangerous, with Firefox allowing the user to keep the download if they choose to.

Avast Anti-virus quarantines the software because it contains FileRep Malware,

Jon Lin's [archive.org] link raises no flags. [Plural Input](https://pluralinput.com/) still works.

I tried them both and both worked as expected and reported.